# How to fix an Android studio Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I changed from Android Studio 1.4 to 1.5 and This is what it displays in "Messages Gradle Sync". P.s: R.layout.ANYTHING appears the "R" as red always too.

```
Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Sara\.AndroidStudio1.4\system\compiler\MyApplication\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: Did you try editing the distributionUrl in *MyApplication\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties* to gradle-2.10-all.zip?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the log you have to change the gradle version editing the file
`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` that you can find in your project.

Use:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: I had the same issue and updated the distributionUrl but I still get the error.

Comment: I had the same issue and updated the distributionUrl but I still get the error.